# How can I add a set to my entity a table with a composite primary key in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am programming an app for a market, using SQL Server. I am using some tables and two of them are `Purchase` and `Products` with a many-to-many relationship between them.

I created another table `PurchaseProduct` to connect them. `PurchaseProduct` has two columns `ProductId` and `PurchaseId` which has relationships with two other tables; this connecting table has a composite primary key including both columns.

Then I tried to add these tables to my Entity Data Model in my Winforms application. It added `Purchase` and `Products`, but not `PurchaseProduct`.

I want to code and show products of a purchase by having a specific `purchaseId`, but I can't reach the missing table. I've added that table but I don't have it in the model.

by the way, I am using Db First, not Code First.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way EF works - and it's a *good thing!*

Basically, both your model classes for products and purchases should have a property of type `ICollection<T>` for the other entity - the `Products` class has a property of all its purchases, and vice-versa.

So if you want the products of a given purchase - find that purchase, and then look in the `Products` property of that class and it should contain all the products for that purchase.

EF "hides away" that relational "join table" since it's really just a helper (or some might call it a kludge) in relational databases to make many-to-many relationships possible.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
public class PurchaseProduct
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ProductsId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PurchaseId { get; set; }
}
```